# cabal install trouble with fay

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, fay

I am trying to run `cabal install fay fay-base`. However, I get the following error:

```
src/Test/CommandLine.hs:18:9:
    Dynamic linking required, but this is a non-standard build (eg. prof).
    You need to build the program twice: once the normal way, and then
    in the desired way using -osuf to set the object file suffix.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
fay-0.14.1.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
fay-base-0.14.1.0 depends on fay-0.14.1.0 which failed to install.
```

I am not sure what it is asking me to do when it asks me to "install once the normal way, and then in the desired way".

Any ideas?

Original Post:

I am trying to run `cabal install fay fay-base`. However, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSsplit-0.2.1.1-ghc7.4.1
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
fay-0.14.1.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
fay-base-0.14.1.0 depends on fay-0.14.1.0 which failed to install.
```

I have received this error on another package install but I cannot remember which one (I believe it was one of the game packages so it was easier to give up). I've tried googling around for -lHSsplit and have been unable to find any help.

Does anyone know what dependency I need to install?

This was solved by installing split `cabal install split` as suggested by Daniel Fischer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What operating system are you using? Also cabal / ghc version?

Comment: `fay` depends on `split`, and the linker can't find the library. Can you verify that you have it (probably in `~/.cabal/lib/split-0.2.1.1`)? And can you try installing `fay` with higher verbosity (`-v3` gives you a lot of output, among that the command lines used to invoke GHC), that may tell somebody what exactly went wrong.

Comment: Installing split allowed me to get further. However, I now get the error posted in my edits above.

Comment: I haven't seen this error, is it still an issue for you? I see that the split dependency isn't listed for fay-tests, but it should not need it either. You could try to cabal unpack or get the repo from github and add it to the .cabal.
Also, more likely that I'll see your question if you tag it with fay :)

Answer (score 1):

I installed it on Arch with ghc 7.4.2, not sure what operating system you're on, but if you're using GNU/Linux (or not) then try upgrading to 7.4.2 and try a fresh install of fay / fay-base.

You might want to try cabal-dev if you haven't already, here's how to do it:
https://github.com/faylang/fay/wiki/Installing-and-running

Scroll a bit down to the cabal-dev part.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu using 7.4.2.